# how to add quotation one in jquery append

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i want to change format onclick from `SendLowongan(000031)` to `SendLowongan('000031')`

this is my code

```
var html = '<div id="buttonSend"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="send" onclick="SendLowongan(' + getdata.IDLowongan + ')"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> Kirim Lowongan</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button></div>';
        $("#footermodal").append(html);
```

Comment: not working for me. the result is ```onclick="SendLowongan(" 000035")"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this part:

```
...."SendLowongan(' + getdata.IDLowongan + ')"....
```

with:

```
..."SendLowongan(\'' + getdata.IDLowongan.trim() + '\')"....
                 ^^                      ^^^^^^^    ^^
```

```js
function SendLowongan(d) {
    console.log('--->' + d + '<----');
}

var getdata = {};
getdata["IDLowongan"] = " 000035";


var html = '<div id="buttonSend"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="send" onclick="SendLowongan(\'' + getdata.IDLowongan.trim() + '\')"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> Kirim Lowongan</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button></div>';
$("#footermodal").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" >


<div id="footermodal"></div>
```